# How can I plot derivatives with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot, sympy

I am having a problem of plotting my derivatives. For example of my equation:

The value of x = 3

f(x) = 6x^2 - 2

f'(x) = 12x

f (3) = 36

```
from scipy.misc import derivative 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol("x")
ex = int(input("What is the value of x in f(x)? "))
coef = int(input("What is the coefficient of the first value? "))
if coef == 1:
    a = int(input("\nWhat is the value of the first coefficient in the equation? ")) #6
    sign = input("What is the operator of the equation? [+] or [-] ") #-
    expo = int(input("What is the value of exponent for the variable x? ")) #2
    ask = input("Does the 2nd value for the equation has constant? [Y] / [N]: ").upper() #y
    if ask == 'Y': #this will be the accepted condition for my example equation
        b = int(input("What is the value of constant? "))
        if sign == '-':
            f = a * x ** expo - b
        elif sign == '+':
            f = a * x ** expo + b
        derivative = sp.diff(f,x) # derivative of the function
        print (derivative) #prints the derivative as a function of x
        print (derivative.subs(x,ex)) # prints the derivative evaluated at x=3

        plt.plot((derivative.subs(x,ex)))
        plt.plot(derivative)
        plt.show()
```

I am getting an error where derivative cannot accept float. I made a comment for every inputs so it will be understood on how my program worked.

```
Error: 
  Message=can't convert expression to float
  Source=D:\VB\Calculus\Calculus\Calculus.py
  StackTrace:
  File "D:\VB\Calculus\Calculus\Calculus.py", line 24, in <module> (Current frame)
    plt.plot(derivative)
```

Comment: "I am getting an error where derivative cannot accept float" - please post the _complete_ error message, starting with the word "Traceback"

Comment: I posted the error

Comment: It might not be the cause of the error, but you seem to import `derivative` from `scipy.misc`, but then you don't use that import but instead assign a new value to it at `derivative = sp.diff(f,x)`.

Comment: I cannot follow but I deleted the import derivative from scipy.misc but still receiving an error

Comment: I think the question should be instead, "How can I plot derivatives *with sympy*?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) requires arrays in order to plot their points, but you are passing to it a `sympy` object.
In order to plot `sympy` object, you should use [**`sympy.plotting.plot`**](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#plot-class):
(I simplified your code in order to make the point clear)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.plotting import plot
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol("x")
ex = 3
a = 6
expo = 2
b = 2

f = a*x**expo - b
derivative = sp.diff(f, x)

plot(derivative, ylabel = "f'(x)")
```

[image]

Comment: Surely there is a way to change the axes' labels?

Comment: Of course there is, I updated my answer: you can pass `ylabel` parameter to `plot`. Notice that it supports latex formatting, you can try with: `ylabel = r"$\frac{df(x)}{dx}$"`